# Can I reheat a sauce in a squeeze bottle?

Tags: reheating

I have some sauces held in squeeze bottles: Low Density Polyethylene (LDPE), recycling code 4, dishwasher safe.

I want to stand them in hot water. Is it safe all the way to boiling point or does LDPE start to deteriorate at a lower temperature?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/science/polyethylene) says LDPE is OK to 110°C but that would leave it pretty close to collapse if it were allowed to touch the pan itself with a burner underneath.

I'd also consider how floppy it might be at 95° or so.

I'd perhaps think of another method.

Comment: Thanks. I tested 70C last night with heat source off it it stood pretty well. I'll push it a bit higher today...